# SDL Video display window: how to attach a window close event callback

Tags: c++, c, video, callback, sdl

I am creating a video player using SDL and I am using C-programming language. In my main function, I create a “for loop” and display the video. After the last video frame is displayed I keep my display window up. When I try to close the window with top-right “X” button, it does not close the window, as there is no callback attached to it. My question is – is there a way to attach a callback to that window’s close event. I am looking for a solution that works on all platforms (windows, linux and mac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDL has SDL_AddEventWatch(), you could set up a filter that calls your handler on SDL_QUIT.  You could also just loop over SDL_WaitEvent() in its own thread, and have that call your callback or execute your code there.

Edit: SDL_WaitEvent() has to be used in the thread that initialized the video system.  Same for the other SDL Event queue things.  So you have to set this up properly, its a design issue.

Comment: Thanks. it looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

Just put that into your main loop for Event Handling, if you don't handle QuitEvent, your window will not be closeable by pressing on the X.

```
SDL_Event evt;

while(SDL_PollEvent(&evt))
{

   switch(evt->type)
   {
      case SDL_QUIT:
      //your quit procedure
      break;
   }

}
```

Comment: I use the event polling in my main function. that works only when you are in the for loop. After I display all the video frames, it's no longer running the for loop behind. Just to clarify, i am creating a dynamic library to do the SDL related work. I am calling that library from another application.

Comment: Normally, you should poll your events at each frames and without details, its hard to give a perfect answer... But you can catch that event and then call a virtual method that is implemented in your application. But this is more C++ solution than C.

Comment: Conceptually the solution might be something like this: from my main function I create new thread that runs an infinite loop. in that loop I poll events and check for window close event; the thread is terminated once a window close event is detected. I don't know much about multi-thread programming. So not sure if that's the right approach for implementing event callback. Not sure either if there is platform independent implementation for multi-thread programming. Any suggestion?

Comment: SDL has threads, and since you're already using it, I guess I would suggest those.  Otherwise pthreads or boost threads, or c++11 std threads, are all cross platform.

Comment: @user26347: thanks for your suggestion; I will try with SDL threads. Question: running a thread having infinite loop and checking for events as I mentioned above- is that a good approach?

Comment: actually, scratch that.  WaitEvent() can only be called from the thread that initialized the video system, so you have something of a design problem.  But yes, I'd just go with a good old for(;;), but use WaitEvent instead of PollEvent, otherwise you will chew up a lot of clock spinning the loop.